# Screen flashes between splash and extended splash in Windows 8 App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I'm writing Windows 8 application, which loads data from internet service, so I'm using extended splash during the loading.
When the app starts it shows Splash screen for a second, and then navigates to ExtendedSplash. During the switch between the splashes it's you can see the screen blink/flash for a fraction of a second. Can I avoid this flashing somehow?

Essentially, in App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
        if (_rootFrame == null)
        {
            _rootFrame = new Frame();
            SuspensionManager.RegisterFrame(_rootFrame, "appFrame");
        }

        // extended splash
        _rootFrame.Navigate(typeof (ExtendedSplash), args.SplashScreen);
        Window.Current.Content = _rootFrame;
        Window.Current.Activate();

        await PerformDataFetch(); // also navigate to main page after loading complete
}
```

Extended splash has the same layout as splash + loading ring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
_rootFrame.Navigate(typeof (ExtendedSplash), args.SplashScreen);
```

you might want to try:

```
//The key is not how you get the new splash screen
_rootFrame.Content = new ExtendedSplash(args.SplashScreen);

//but rather in how you GET TO the Splash Screen... 
// Navigation will trigger a complete refresh, reassigning a value should not. 
Window.Current.Content = _rootFrame;
```

In this way you will avoid triggering the Navigation Events that refresh the screen. And the content of the Frame should update seamlessly.